# C difference between char function(void) and void function(void)

Tags: c, char, void, spi, atmega16

For my thesis I'm using an ATmega16 to communicate with MCP2515 over SPI. When we are checking the example code to set up SPI as a slave mode in the Atmega16 datasheet we get next example code.

```
void SPI_SlaveInit(void)
{
/* Set MISO output, all others input */
    DDR_SPI = (1<<DD_MISO);
/* Enable SPI */
    SPCR = (1<<SPE);
}
char SPI_SlaveReceive(void)
{
/* Wait for reception complete */
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))
;
/* Return data register */
    return SPDR;
}
```

We don't understand why they are using char SPI_SlaveReceive(void) instead of just void  SPI_SlaveReceive(void).
Can somebody explain us why they use the char instead of void? What is the difference? 
I can't find a good explanation on the internet.

Comment: `SPI_SlaveReceive` is not returning anything, so no return type other than `void`. What is problem in that

Comment: char SPI_SlaveReceive(void) takes nothing when called, and returns a char. void SPI_SlaveInit(void) takes nothing, returns nothing

Comment: Because "they" want to return a value?

Answer (score 1):

`SPI_SlaveReceive` receives something, so it's returning that "something" as a `char`, hence the return type. If it was typed to return `void` you wouldn't be able to get the received value, which wouldn't be very useful!

If it didn't return what it received how would you ever get what was received..?